# angular2 material checkbox checked or not

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular-material

I am using angular 2 with material. I want to get the material checkbox checked or not when clicking the checkbox. I have done by passing click event to the component function. But it does not work when using material checkbox. It only works when using html check box.

```
<md-checkbox class="example-radio-button" [value]="hobby 1" (click)="hobbyClicked($event)">
    hobby 1
</md-checkbox>


hobbyClicked(evt){
    console.log(evt.target.checked);   // undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[ngModel]` & `(change)` directive, based on checkbox is checked or not, you could retrieve a value from DOM.

```
<md-checkbox class="example-radio-button" 
  [ngModel]="hobby" value="hoby 1"
  (change)="hobbyClicked($event)">
    hobby 1
</md-checkbox>
```

**Code**

```
hobbyClicked(evt){
  console.log(evt.checked ? evt.source.value: '');   // undefined
}
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jaqQIHAmmk3sJGBFbRC4?p=preview)